# Is a trade done in forex when (Ask price = 1) < (Bid price = 2)? and in which price?

Tags: trading, foreign-exchange, financial-advisor

In forex market, in a normal mode when `Ask` = `Bid`, trade is done.

And If `Ask = 2` (the lowest price by sellers) > `Bid = 1` (the highest price by buyers), so the market is not liquid and no trade would be done because no Bid/Ask price is matched.

But what if `Ask = 1` < `Bid = 2`?
And in which price the trade would be done?

Answer (score 2):

A Market Order or **Marketable** Limit Order does not "enter" the order book.

If the incoming order is "better than or equal to" the other side of existing order book, the trade will be executed **instantly** at the price quoted by the **existing** orders.

This means if the existing Ask = 1, Bid < Ask, and suddenly an incoming buy order = 2 comes in, the trade will be executed at 1, and the order book & quotation never shows Bid = 2. Assuming that the existing quantity available at the one best price is more than or equal to the incoming order. Whichever is existing is the price.

There is no such thing as a Buy order and Sell order submitted "at the same time". The system tracks the sequence in addition to timestamp.

In summary, the quotations of Bid is always < Ask for Forex.

Comment: Your last sentence is "In summary, the quotations of Bid is always < Ask for Forex." would you explain it more?